# checking map values c++

Tags: c++, maps

I need to go through the values in a map and check how many are > 0. I don't know how to do this without looping.

```
#include <map>
using std::map;
#include <string>
using std::string;
#include <iostream>
using std::cout; using std::endl;

int exists(const map<string, int> &m) {
  int count = 0; 
  for (auto &p : m) {
    if (p.second > 0) {
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count;
}

int main() {
  const std::map<std::string, int> stuff = {
  {"book", 0},
  {"pencil", 7},
  {"eraser", 0},
  {"calculator", 1},
  {"rivers", 1},
  {"fish", 2},
  {"people", 0},
};

  int num = exists(stuff);
  cout << num;
}
```

outputs "4" because there are only 4 keys in the map that have a >0 value. I basically need this without the for loop, or a while loop.

Comment: If this is for an assignment or a personal challenge, look to recursion. If not, don't waste your time. The loop's the simplest, most logical, and probably most efficient solution.

Comment: You could use copy_if to duplicate the map only with the items that match, although that's heavy weight. Better would be std::count_if. But internally, it will still loop.

Comment: [`std::count_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) will hide the loop (and eliminate the need for the function).

Comment: Re: `I basically need this without the for loop, or a while loop.` - what about `goto`? :)

Comment: Why do you need to do this without looping? Is it just `for` and `while` that are prohibited or any looping? If this is an educational assignment, the goal might be for you to find something in the standard library that accomplishes the task in one line.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this:

```
std::map<std::string, int>::const_iterator iter = stuff.begin();
unsigned int quantity = 0;
if (iter->second == 0) ++quantity;
++iter;

if (iter->second == 0) ++quantity;
++iter;

if (iter->second == 0) ++quantity;
++iter;

if (iter->second == 0) ++quantity;
++iter;

if (iter->second == 0) ++quantity;
++iter;

if (iter->second == 0) ++quantity;
++iter;

if (iter->second == 0) ++quantity;
++iter;

if (iter->second == 0) ++quantity;
++iter;
```

Let's call this technique "loop flattening".  With "loop unrolling", a portion of the loop content is copied.  Here, the entire loop is "flattened".

An iterator is used to visit each item in the `map`.  Incrementing the iterator will point to the "next" item in the `map`.

*Note:  This technique is feasible for containers of small quantities.  However, loops are still the preferred technique.*